# Comparison of two series of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it possible to prove or find a counterexample of the statement
"If $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$ are two sequences of real numbers such that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ either converges or diverges to $-\infty$."?

Comment: If $a_n, b_n$ are positive then your statement is true. Otherwise , take $b_n=\frac 1{2^n} $ and $a_n=-k$ where $k\gt 0$ is a constant. Lots of other examples can also be formed.

Comment: Thanks! I have modified the question.

Comment: or $a_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $c_n = b_n-a_n \gt 0$

Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N c_n$ is increasing and thus either it converges or it diverges to $+\infty$ as $N \to \infty$

So, since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b_n$ converges as $N \to \infty$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N b_n - \sum\limits_{n=1}^Nc_n$ must either converge or diverge to $-\infty$ as $N \to \infty$